# Setup Evolution plugin for MS Exchange on Fedora 11

Tags: fedora, evolution

Can anyone please guide me (or point to a nice guide) on how to set up the Evolution plugin for MS Exchange on Fedora 11? I tried installing from source, but got pretty much lost in woods. It would be great to have as simple guide (like yum install something) - if it is possible. If I have to deal with sources, I would appreciate a very detailed step-by-step guide for dummy.

Thanks!

Comment: Talking to Exchange 2003 is very different than talking to Exchange 2007, please tell us which you're wanting to connect to. Also, there are two Evolution plugins for Exchange: The Exchange Plugin, and the Exchange MAPI plugin.

Comment: It would be Exchange 2007. I don't really know th edifference between the two plugins you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the Exchange plugin for Evolution:

```
pkcon install evolution-exchange
```

After this you can choose *Microsoft Exchange* as server type when creating a new Evolution mail account. You have to enter your username (maybe in form `<domain>\<user>`) and the URL to the Outlook Web Access (OWA URL). After a click on *Authenticate* you should be asked for your password. If you entered all information correctly, the name of your mailbox should have been filled in in the *Mailbox* field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Fedora handy to test, but IIRC it is actually installed by default (or it was in earlier versions of Fedora).  If it is not installed, it should just be a matter of typing

> **yum install evolution**

Answer (score 0):

yum install evolution-exchange    from root